# Can I have an alternate main sourceSet in a gradle project?

Tags: gradle, source-sets

I am writing a training task with a set of tests and code in the main sourceSet. I would also like to provide a sample answer in a separate sourceSet which can be run with a separate task. Is there a way to run the same set of tests over two different main soureSets?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is possible by removing the main sourceSet from the runtime classpath as follows:

```
task testAnswers(type: Test) {
    description = "Runs tests against the example answer"                       
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.answers.output.classesDir                       
    classpath -= sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath                               
    classpath += sourceSets.answers.runtimeClasspath
}
```